# Python counter and values

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get the assert statements below to return `True`

```
assert len_multi(Counter('aabbcc')) == 6
assert len_multi(Counter('aaa')) == 3
assert len_multi(Counter()) == 0
```

What I initially wrote is

```
from collections import Counter
def len_multi():
    myList = ('aabbcc')
    multiList = Counter(myList)
    multiA = sum(multiList.values())
    print(multiA)
len_multi()
```

So I think what I'm doing is wrong is including another Counter within the function. So I'm applying a Counter to a Counter?

So I tried this, but still can't get of the counter?

```
multiA = ('aabbcc')
print(sum(Counter(multiA).values()))
```

I think what I need to do is assign the value given in the assert statement to a pre-defined variable?

Any pointers would be super helpful.

Comment: your indentation is broken - and important to understand what belongs where

Comment: Sorry, I should of mentioned that I've indented it correctly in my shell, just copied and pasted poorly.

Comment: The code gives me the correct result as long as I manually insert the arguments from the assert function into my code.

Comment: Your `len_multi()` doesn't accept any arguments; that should be your first focus here. Do you know how to use function arguments yet? Your `Counter()` call is applied to another string (assigned to `myList` in the function), neither of which has anything to do with what `len_multi(Counter('aabbcc'))` would pass in as an argument.

Comment: I get the basics of function arguments and I thought something similar to what you've said. I thought if I left the parentheses empty, it would be filled with the argument given in the assert statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont actualy understand what you tryna do but here i correct your code:

```
from collections import Counter

def len_multi(multiList):
    multiA = sum(multiList.values())
    return(multiA)

assert len_multi(Counter('aabbcc')) == 6 #True program goes on
assert len_multi(Counter('aaa')) == 0    #False you get an assertion error
```